# Passing parameter into function calling that looks like this: @click="${hello}

Tags: javascript, function, web

If a function is called this way
`@click="${hello}"`, how can I pass parameter into it?

The function works fine for me if it looks like this:
`function hello() {...}` but won't work anymore if the function expects any parameter like `function hello(parameter) {...}`, because calling `@click="${hello()}` or `@click=${hello(parameter}`} result in some Unhandled Promise Rejection error.

What is the name of this style of calling function (`@click="${hello}`) and how do I properly pass parameter into it?

Comment: `@click="${function(){hello(parameter)}}"` Will that help?

Comment: Are you using some web framework that is forcing you to make calls in that manner? If so, you should tag it in the question -- the context will help the community provide you better answers.

Comment: @samuellawrentz That does the job! What is the name of this style of calling function and what should I google if I want to learn more about it?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I am using the PWA Starter Kit found [here](https://polymer.github.io/pwa-starter-kit/) and this is how the functions are called in the kit. I have never seen this style of calling and it would be great if I just know what to google if I want to learn more about it!

Comment: Glad I could help! When you use parenthesis`()` the function gets invoked. So what we are doing is that we encapsulate the function call `hello()` within a new function that is not invoked. Read regarding `callbacks` and `passing a function as parameter`.
Also the `${}` syntax you are using is more related to template strings - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @samuellawrentz Why does calling hello() directly `@click="${hello()}` results in that Unhandled Promise Rejection error, and yet calling hello() as a callback in another function `@click="${function(){hello(parameter)}}"` works without a problem?

Comment: When ever HTML is parsed in a browser, if it sees a function ending with `()`. The browser tries to invoke that function. It doesn't care if it is a click event or a hover event. It just calls `hello()` during page load. 
I guess that is why you go those errors. 
The reason for that error: `hello()` gets invoked at the page load, even before you clicked it.